# Android react native java null pointer exception

Tags: android, react-native, nullpointerexception

My large react-native application crashes sometimes with following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode.addChildAt(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.setChildren(UIImplementation.java:482)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.setChildren(UIManagerModule.java:441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This does not happen always, therefore hard to reproduce this error. What could be the reason for this exception.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17123

Comment: Can't we add a safe guard for not to occur this error, since this error displays `no a null object reference`

Comment: what is the react native version that you're using?

Comment: versin is 0.55.1.

Comment: Are you using Wix/React-Native-Navigation? Because we used to get this error a lot when using Wix/React-Native-Navigation, but after switching to react-navigation, we haven't got this even once. Though we had to optimize some of our views to get smooth animations in react-navigation.

Comment: @GayanCharith upgrade react-native version, and if you are using react-native-navigation upgrade it too